# AFRAME: Motion-capture-components autoSaveFile missing

Tags: aframe

I can't save the files from the motion capture component ( https://github.com/dmarcos/aframe-motion-capture-components) to my local drive (local storage in browser works). According to the documentation there is a 'autoSaveFile', but when I add this

it gives me this error "autoSaveFile`for component/system`avatar-recorder". (Nor does pressing 'u'). Does anybody know how to save recordings to local drive or am I doing something wrong entirely?

(example site: https://recording.glitch.me/ ) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The motion capture tools are a part of the A-Frame Inspector now. Click the camera icon on the top left.

Comment: Thanks, This solution works also on oculus go if you open the inspector programmatically. :-)